# Spark: Hive Insert overwrite throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I have this code that saves the schemaRDD (person) to a Hive table stored as parquet (person_parquet)

```
      hiveContext.sql("insert overwrite table person_parquet select * from person")
```

But it throws an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdConfOnlyAuthorizerFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setupAuth(SessionState.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.getAuthenticator(SessionState.java:867)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.getUserFromAuthenticator(SessionState.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getEmptyTable(Table.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.<init>(Table.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.newTable(Hive.java:2566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadTable(Hive.java:1464)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Command$class.execute(commands.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.execute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDDLike$class.$init$(SchemaRDDLike.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.<init>(SchemaRDD.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sql(HiveContext.scala:94)
    at com.example.KafkaConsumer$$anonfun$main$2.apply(KafkaConsumer.scala:114)
    at com.example.KafkaConsumer$$anonfun$main$2.apply(KafkaConsumer.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:529)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:529)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:171)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdConfOnlyAuthorizerFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthorizeProviderManager(HiveUtils.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setupAuth(SessionState.java:381)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdConfOnlyAuthorizerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthorizeProviderManager(HiveUtils.java:366)
    ... 30 more
```

---

1. I changed my hive-site.xml to this but still throws the same exception

   ```
   <property>hive.security.authenticator.manager</property>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.HadoopDefaultAuthenticator</value> 

   <property>hive.security.authorization.enabled</property>
   <value>false</value>

   <property>hive.security.authorization.manager</property
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.DefaultHiveAuthorizationProvid‌​er</value>
   ```
2. (same hive-site.xml as #1) When I added the hive-exec 1.0 in my dependencies, it threw a different exception (AbstractMethodError)
3. (same hive-site.xml as #1) I tried adding hive-exec 0.13 to my dependencies. During first run (insert), it still throws an error, but on second and succeeding insert, it's successful.

I am using Sandbox HDP 2.2 (Hive 0.14.0.2.2.0.0-2041) and Spark 1.2.0.

Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

"SQLStdConfOnlyAuthorizerFactory" class has been added in hive 0.14.0 version ([HIVE-8045](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8045)) but Spark 1.2 depends on hive 0.13. Your hive-site.xml must be having "hive.security.authorization.manager" set as "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdConfOnlyAuthorizerFactory " and your classpath musn't be having hive-exec 0.14 JAR thats why its throwing ClassNotFoundException. So either include your hive-exec 0.14.0 JAR in classpath (and before Spark's own hive JARs) or change your entry in hive-site.xml to something like this :-

```
<property>
  <name>hive.security.authorization.manager</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.DefaultHiveAuthorizationProvider</value>
</property>
```

Former is not recommended since similar issues may arise further due to hive version mismatch

Comment: Still throws an error. 

Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-1" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdConfOnlyAuthorizerFactory.createHiveAuthorizer(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/security/authorization/plugin/HiveMetastoreClientFactory;Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf;Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/security/HiveAuthenticationProvider;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/security/authorization/plugin/HiveAuthorizer;

Comment: I have this settings:
"hive.security.authenticator.manager" set as
"org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.HadoopDefaultAuthenticator" and
"hive.security.authorization.enabled" set as "false" and "hive.security.authorization.manager" set as "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.DefaultHiveAuthorizationProvider"

Comment: Can you install hive 13 instead of hive 14 on your machine and try? Also, what version of spark are you on?

Comment: I am using Sandbox HDP 2.2 (Hive 0.14.0.2.2.0.0-2041) and Spark 1.2.0. 
When I only edited the hive-site.xml, it still threw a ClassNotFoundException. 
When I added the hive-exec 1.0 in my dependencies, it threw a different exception posted above (AbstractMethodError).

Comment: I tried adding hive-exec 0.13 to my dependencies. During first run (insert), it still throws an error, but on second and succeeding insert, it's successful.

Comment: That's weird! Remember hive is not just about hive-exec. Hive contains lot of other project as well (like hive-serde,hive-shims etc). From here I can recommend you to run spark with a hadoop distribution having hive-0.13. Even Spark 1.3 supports hive-0.13 AFAIK. If you still want this distribution only, I think the best alternative is to have the spark assembly JAR as the first JAR in your classpath(as it internally contains all hive0.13 JARS) and then manually debug any issues if they still arise due to compatibility issues(which will be a lot of cumbersome).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value for

`hive.security.authorization.manager = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.DefaultHiveAuthorizationProvider`

worked.

Changed the hive-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you have duplicate jars on the classpath.